# Django's Core Migrate Tool vs South for Django Data Migrations

Tags: django, django-south, django-migrations

I'm not currently using migrations in my Django project but I intend to very soon. I understand that South is the de facto tool, and I was going to use that but then I read on the Django  project site that the development version (I guess to be released as 1.7) has a core migration tool, ran as `migrate`.

Coming from very little experience using migration tools (I installed Django-CMS with South and played around with it for a day or so), which is the best one for a beginner?

Also, since migration itself is pretty young, and Django's version even more so, would I be better off going with South this point?

Finally, another question is if I start with South (most of my Django projects are v1.5), when I upgrade to 1.6 and then 1.7, will I have trouble converting to Django's core migration?

Comment: related question: how to provide an upgrade path from South apps to Django 1.7 migrations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597240/upgrade-path-for-re-usable-apps-with-south-and-django-1-7-migrations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its easy to drop South migration history and initialize any other kind of migration tool.

Django core migrations are based on South, so I *guess* it will be possible to export South migration history to Django core migrations.

Since Django core migrations are not released yet, and your purpose is to learn, I suggest starting with South.

Comment: I installed south and converted my apps and it worked nicely. Since I'm not quite ready to upgrade Django, this plan seems like a good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Since the Andrew Godwin (creator or Django Core migration) words about this change are: "South's four-year-old design hitting serious limits, it's time to add migration support into Django itself", i won't bet on the ability to export South migration history to Django core migrations.

That's why, if you can, I would suggest you to wait for 20th January: the Django 1.7 alpha version with Core Migration will be released as you can see [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Version1.7Roadmap).

Eventually, [Andrew Godwin worked on South himself](https://bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/south/), so you should not see Django Core Migration as a whole new tool, but rather as South v2.

Then, you can be pretty sure that South won't be really maintained as soon as Core migration is released.

That's why I suggest waiting for a few time and giving a chance to this new tool :)

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for Django 1.7 discusses upgrading from South:

> If you already have pre-existing migrations created with South 0.x, then the upgrade process to use `django.db.migrations` is quite simple:
>
> - Ensure all installs are fully up-to-date with their migrations
> - Delete all your (numbered) migration files, but not the directory or **init**.py - make sure you remove the .pyc files too.
> - Run python manage.py makemigrations. Django should see the empty migration directories and make new initial migrations in the new format.
> - Run python manage.py migrate. Django will see that the tables for the initial migrations already exist and mark them as applied without running them.
>
> That’s it! The only complication is if you have a circular dependency loop of foreign keys; in this case, makemigrations might make more than one initial migration, and you’ll need to mark them all as applied using:
>
> ```
> python manage.py migrate --fake yourappnamehere
> ```

(from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south)).

Comment: >Django will see that the tables for the initial migrations already exist and mark them as applied without running them.

Apparently, not always. I get the error "django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "[table]" already exists".  Running migrate app 0001 --fake will fix it though.