# Upgrade path for re-usable apps with South AND django 1.7 migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

Or: can Django 1.7 users still use South?

I'm the maintainer of a re-usable app. Our policy is to always support the latest two versions of Django. We have an extensive set of South migrations and, we want to support the new Django 1.7 migration system going forward.

What I'm confused with is how I can allow developers to use my app with both Django 1.6 (and South) and Django 1.7 (new migrations).

The Django Documentation recommends [just deleting all the pre-existing South migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south). But this is not an option, since I need to keep them around for my Django 1.6 users.

The closest to an upgrade path I could come up with, is not use the new migration system until I drop support for Django <1.7 in my app (so when Django 1.8 comes out). But what about the naming clash with the migrate command? Both South and the new system use `python manage.py migrate` to run migrations. So Django 1.7 users can't use South anymore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**South 1.0** provides the solution. It will look first in a `south_migrations/` folder and fallback to `migrations/`. So in your case of third-party libraries needing to support older and newer Djangos: move South files to `south_migration/` and create new 1.7 migrations in `migrations/`.

- South 1.0 [release notes](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releasenotes/1.0.html)
- [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#libraries-third-party-apps) have also added this information

South cannot be used with Django 1.7, but that's not a problem for end users. They either use new Django or older Djangos with South 1.0. There won't be a South 2.0, which was going to backport new 1.7-style migrations. Also @Ondrej's answer is correct just it was written before South 1.0 was released so the truth back then (mere months ago) consisted only of workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

There's are settings both in Django ([`MIGRATION_MODULES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#migration-modules)) and in South ([`SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#south-migration-modules)) which let you specify module with migrations. So you have 2 options:

- put Django 1.7 migrations to new folder and let Django 1.7 users know they should set `MIGRATION_MODULES` to given folder.
- move South migrations to new folder and let South users know a new version of your app is backwards incompatible and they should set `SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES` to given folder in order to continue using it.

[Here's an article](http://treyhunner.com/2014/03/migrating-to-django-1-dot-7/) describing more or less the same. Plus [an app](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-email-log) that already made changes to support both South and Django 1.7.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping for a solution where it would "just work" for re-usable apps. This approach requires extra configuration per app in the project.

Comment: South and Django migrations (South 2.0) aren't compatible, so unfortunatelly it'll probably never work that way. It's not that much of an extra work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you are in luck, if you go over to the [kickstarter page](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/andrewgodwin/schema-migrations-for-django) you see its funding(£17,952) allows for the 7,000 + tasks including:

> A backport of the key features to a new major version of South to support those on Django 1.4 and 1.5

so if you are willing you can upgrade your 1.6 south to at least match django migrations. I know its not exactly what you asked for, but it seems to be the only way.